# Avoid @Html.Action helper catch exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, exception, html-helper

When an inner action is throwing an exception in a view. `@Html.Action("BugyAction")` The action method seems to catch the exception and re-throw it as an inner exception. That is very frustrating for debugging the inner action.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior where VisualStudio is showing you the exception thrown by the helper method `Action`?

Comment: Can you say what you want to achieve and why the current behavior does not fit?

Answer (score 0):

You can break on any exception in Visual Studio.  Here is an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) explaining how to set that up.

Make sure to rethrow an exception in the code (ex: Controller) so that it will be caught and your program breaks at the appropriate line and you don't suppress the exception.

```
        public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        int something = 0;
        try
        {
            int y = 3 / something;  //Intentional Exception
            return new ActionResult();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```